# How to grep Bcast for Android?

Tags: android, linux, bash, shell, awk

I used `ifconfig wlan0 | grep Bcast | awk '{print $3}'` to get `Bcast:172.123.123.123`, but I want to get 172.123.123.123 only. I tried:

`ifconfig wlan0 | grep Bcast | awk '{print $3}' | grep ^0\.0\.0\.0` and `ifconfig wlan0 | grep Bcast | awk '{print $3}' | grep '[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}'` and both captured nothing.

Comment: try `ifconfig wlan0 | awk '/Bcast/{split($3,a,":"); print a[2]}'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this: `ifconfig wlan0 | grep Bcast | awk '{print $3}' | grep -oE '[0-9.,]+'`

Answer (score 0):

`ip` is generally easier to parse than `ifconfig`.

```
ip -o addr show dev wlp3s0 | awk '{ for (i = 3; i < NF; i += 2) if ($i == "brd") { j = i + 1; print $j } }'
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use below command to extract the second ip address (first would be inet addr) from the output of `ifconfig wlan0` directly.

`ifconfig wlan0 | awk -v FPAT='[0-9]+\\.[0-9]+\\.[0-9]+\\.[0-9]+' '($1=$1){print $2}'`